# I have a modal that disappears automaticly when I click it on joomla bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, modal-dialog

The case is that I have in my joomla bootstrap a modal that displays a fade in window with some information, but for any reason that escapes my understanding, when I click on the modal button, the window appears and disappears without any reason. I look at the css and html code and I cannot see any strange result.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: What version of Joomla/Bootstrap?

Comment: Joomla 3.3.6 on the MasterBootstrap template

Comment: It looks like you have loaded bootstrap.js twice.